# SharePoint 2013 Caml Query on GUID using CSOM returns empty

Tags: 2013, caml-query, document, guid

I'm trying to find a file in a folder by GUID. There is a reason behind it, because I get GUID in document set history and I cannot rely on a file name.

I'm stuck trying all the possible combinations of GUD/UniqueId for internal field name and possibilities for Value Type. If I search for a specific title, the 'same' code works.

What am I doing wrong? What id the proper internal field name and value type. If I search in UI for the file in a specified library by GUID used in code, it finds it, so there should not be problem in configuration.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using DM = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String SharepointURL = "SP-URL";
            String DocLibName = "LibName";
            Guid itemGuid = new Guid("1156a28e-0c98-4c36-ac0a-fbc71d137dbd");

            SP.ClientContext context = new SP.ClientContext(SharepointURL);
            SP.Web web = context.Web;
            SP.List docLib = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibName);
            context.Load(docLib);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            SP.CamlQuery query = new SP.CamlQuery();

            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type=\"Text\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type=\"Guid\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type=\"Text\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type=\"Guid\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
            query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);

            ////This search is working
            //String value = "The test document";
            //query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", value);

            SP.ListItemCollection collListItem = docLib.GetItems(query);
            docLib.Context.Load(collListItem);
            docLib.Context.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637101/how-to-get-a-document-on-sharepoint-by-its-unique-id) if it helps.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the article you are proposing? As far as I understand it does not search by GUID, it is using ID instead? I need to search by GUID which cannot be searched for in any other way, as far as I know, but using CamlQery

Answer (score 2):

there is no **SPList.GetItemByUniqueId** if you can use id try **GetFileById(id)**

If you can't use id In caml query use one of theses queries

**Query 1**

```
query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid);
```

**Query 2**

```
query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid)
```

Comment: I wish it would help. I have tried it - copy/paste bot of those, but both return 0 items. Is there a chance there is something wrong with configuration? I can even see index set on GUID in a library:
You have created 3 of maximum 20 indices on this list. These indices are:

    Content Type
    GUID
    Modified By